# in angular, sourceMap and aot/buildOptimizer Can't they be generated at the same time?

Tags: angular

sourceMap and aot/buildOptimizer  Can't they be generated at the same time?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mpVb.png)

Comment: Well it would make nosense at all. SourceMap are useful in certain cases and by enable them your dist will grow up in size drastically / you will able to debug it directly from browser. BuildOptimizer is indeed used when you don't want to have those sourceMaps and for other stuff. Why would you need such a strange build setting?

Comment: I want to upload the sourcemap to the error interception platform for source mapping, and then delete the sourcemap before publishing to the official environment to give users a good experience

Comment: Why don't you just make two builds, one for the interception platform and the other for production? you can look about Ivy, it will help you out: https://angular.io/guide/ivy